# Taintflow analysis in dotnet

Tags: .net, security, reverse-engineering, bytecode, static-analysis

I want to do taint flow analysis in dotnet bytecode. I want to find all the tainted sources in the given dotnet bytecode and then all the program points affected by these tainted sources in it. I want to do static analysis of dotnet bytecode but I don't know which tool would be helpful for me. I am new to dotnet and also I am a linux user. Can someone help me with the tools, documentation or specific website related to my topic.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a project called [Roslyn Security Guard](https://dotnet-security-guard.github.io/). The project page mention that they do Taint analysis:

> Taint analysis is the capability to track variables in the code flow
>   and trace variable coming from user input.

They have a [configuration file](https://github.com/dotnet-security-guard/roslyn-security-guard/blob/master/RoslynSecurityGuard/Config/Sinks.yml) (yaml) for sinks which can become dangerous if tainted data flows into them.

But you mentioned, that you would like to analyse dotnet bytecode. Though Roslyn is for C# or VB.net Source-Code, you can get results if you use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and save the decompiled assembly as project (ILSpy: "Save Assembly as C# Project").